# Hook into Events from ActiveX lib from console application

Tags: c#, event-handling, interop, activex

I'm trying to use the OnTransaction event in an activex library from a console application.
From the object browser I can see the following objects:

1. AxInteropDummySDKLib - namespace
2. AxDummySDK - Class
3. AxDummySDKEventMulticaster - Class
4. _DDummySDKEvents_OnMessageEvent - Class
5. _DDummySDKEvents_OnTransactionEvent - Class
6. _DDummySDKEvents_OnMessageEventHandler - Delegate
7. _DDummySDKEvents_OnTransactionEventHandler - Delegate

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You might try by starting here:

[How to establish a COM event sink in the .NET Framework with return values by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811645)